# Compile files without certain substring

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm new to bash, I was wondering how I would go about compiling files in a certain directory that don't contain certain strings in name. So say I have gumbo.java jackson.java roosevelt.java roar.java as my files in directory. How do I compile files that don't contain roar or gumbo in the name?

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you can use an extended glob pattern like this:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
printf '%s\n' !(roar|gumbo).java
```

This matches anything other than `roar` or `gumbo`, that ends in `.java`. You can think of it as `*.java`, minus `roar.java` and `gumbo.java`.

Substitute the `printf` for whatever you're using to compile, if you're happy with the output.

If you want to negate anything that contains those substrings, you can add some asterisks:

```
printf '%s\n' !(*@(roar|gumbo)*).java
```

The `@()` matches any one of the pipe-separated options. As before, the whole thing is negated with `!()`.

As suggested in the comments, I also enabled `nullglob` so that an empty match expands to nothing.

Comment: What if the file is roarroar.java, this will not get ignored despite roar being a substring.

Comment: `!(*roar*|*gumbo*).java` otherwise with find `find . -maxdepth 0 -name '*.java' \! -name '*roar*.java' \! -name '*gumbo*.java' -exec printf '%s\n' {} + `

Comment: @Nahuel I think it's more complicated than that, as the `*` need to be optional

Comment: @TomFenech, no because `*` matches null string, however `@()` is a good idea can save 2 `*`

Comment: @Nahuel you're right about the `*`, thanks, I edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the find command:

```
find . -type f -not -name '*roar*' -and -not -name '*gumbo*' -exec <command> {} \;
```

For example:

```
find . -type f -not -name '*roar*' -and -not -name '*gumbo*' -exec javac {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a standard loop:

```
for file in *.java; do
  case $file in
  *roar*|*gumbo*) continue;;
  *) javac "$file";;
  esac
done
```